# How to get static value from Class by its name, using string?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public sealed class Constant
{
    public static readonly string WHITE = "white";
    public static readonly string RED = "red";
    public static readonly string EMPTY = "";
    public static readonly string FIELD = "field_";
    public static readonly Field PAWN_WHITE = new Field(false, false, true, WHITE);
    public static readonly Field DAME_WHITE = new Field(false, false, true, WHITE);
    public static readonly Field PAWN_RED = new Field(false, true, false, RED);
    public static readonly Field DAME_RED = new Field(false, false, true, RED);
    public static readonly Field EMPTY_FIELD = new Field(true, false, false, EMPTY);
}
```

And i am using values from that class like that (without creating object):

```
Field tmp = Constant.PAWN_RED;
```

Now i want achieve something like that:

```
public void MyMethod(string constantName)
{
    Field tmp = Constant.get-Value-From-My-Class-Using-Value's-Name(constantName);
}
```

I hope you know what I mean. I need to get that "constant" dynamically using its names. So i need string parameter.
I am still newbie in C# so please don't blame me if this question is stupid or something :-)

Comment: Try `typeof(Constant).GetField(constantName).GetValue(null)`

Comment: Wow man, that was exactly what i needed. Thanks!!! :D 
Could you tell me please - is that "operation" have name or something? You know like "override, extend,  etc."

Comment: That is accomplished via [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection).